# Simple Eager / Lazy loading examples in linq2sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Does anyone have a simple code example in linq2sql that demonstrates the difference between Eager Loading and Lazy Loading?

Comment: LINQ is just a set of extension methods and language syntax.  You probably mean Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL, or perhaps _deferred execution_.

Comment: @SLaks Yes I meant Lin2Sql. I've updated the question. Now I am confused :-) I thought deferred execution was lazy loading? I guess this is a separate question.

Comment: Deferred Execution is where a query is not executed until it's actually used. Lazy-Loading is sort of the same, except your deferring the loading of an association until it's actually needed. This is a good link for understanding deferred execution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: @zener - No problem, do you need help with Eager/Lazy loading in L2S? Or understanding what the difference between the two are?

Comment: @Phil I was looking to understand when you would use either, hopefully a code example would help explain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **Deferred Loading:** for a given entity, it's associated collections may be empty when it is first loaded, but when these collections are first iterated, LINQ to SQL fires off a query to load these collections after it is loaded the collection is then available for future use without requiring another query:

  ```
  var query = from o in db.GetTable<Order>() //db is the datacontext
          select o;
  foreach(Order o in query)
  {
      foreach(OrderDetail d in o.OrderDetails)//Deferred loading
      {
         //Do something on these collections
      }
  }
  ```

The `OrderDetails` are loaded only if it is iterated, so If the `OrderDetatils` are never iterated the corresponding query is never executed.

- **Eager Loading:** immediate loading the associated Collections for all referenced entities for example LINQ to SQL will automatically brings all the `OrderDetails` for all the retreived Orders

  ```
  DataLoadOptions op = new DataLoadOptions();
  op.LoadWith<Order>(o => o.OrderDetails);
  db.LoadOptions = op;
  var query = from o in db.GetTable<Order>() 
           select o;
  foreach(Order o in query)
  { 
      //Order details are eager loaded; additional queries are not needed
      foreach(OrderDetail d in o.OrderDetails)
      {
         //do something
      }
  }
  ```

note that: **Deferred execution is a LINQ Feature** but **Deferred Loading is a LINQ to SQL feature**

Comment: 'Deffered Loading' is Lazy Loading and is a feature of pretty much every ORM.

Comment: @Phill of course it is a feature for almost every ORM but i add this as a note to be a distinction between them as all the comments above pointed to deffered execution but the OP question was about the deffered Loading so in this context it is valid

Comment: I know, my point is it's the same thing, just L2S call it something different. So for someone coming along to this question and seeing the answer going "why is he talking about deferred execution", they know it's just Lazy Loading with a different name in L2S.